# Problem when importing basemap: KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

When I install basemap I obtained an "already done" code:

```
Requirement already satisfied: basemap in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyproj>=1.9.3 in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from 
basemap) (1.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib!=3.0.1,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages (from basemap) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from basemap) 
(1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyshp>=1.2.0 in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from 
basemap) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.2.1 in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from 
basemap) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages 
(from matplotlib!=3.0.1,>=1.0.0->basemap) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages 
(from matplotlib!=3.0.1,>=1.0.0->basemap) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in 
c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.0.1,>=1.0.0->basemap) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from 
matplotlib!=3.0.1,>=1.0.0->basemap) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from 
kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib!=3.0.1,>=1.0.0->basemap) (46.0.0)
```

But when I want to import it I obtain the following error

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
2 import numpy as np
3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap_init_.py in
150
151 # create dictionary that maps epsg codes to Basemap kwargs.
--> 152 pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB']
153 epsgf = open(os.path.join(pyproj_datadir,'epsg'))
154 epsg_dict={}

~\Anaconda3\lib\os.py in getitem(self, key)
676 except KeyError:
677 # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 678 raise KeyError(key) from None
679 return self.decodevalue(value)
"680

KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'
```

I have done some google research and apparently there is a problem with the libraires version. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'c:\Users\Paisa\anaconda3\Library\share'
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

You should substitute "Paisa" by your "username"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the directory that contains "_epsg.py".  For me, it is:
C:\Users(username)\anaconda3\pkgs\cartopy-0.18.0-py38h2a8b5ed_8\Lib\site-packages\cartopy

Then, as the original poster says,

```
import os

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'c:\Users\(username)\anaconda3\pkgs\cartopy-0.18.0-py38h2a8b5ed_8\Lib\site-packages\cartopy' # or path to your file
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```